# Stack Using Struct or Class to implement its private data

Tags: c++, class, struct, stack

I want to implement a Stack Class by using linked list. 
Here is how I define in header file .For each element in the Stack, there are two data in the element:

```
#ifndef MYSTACK_H_INCLUDED
#define MYSTACK_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyStack{
public:
    MyStack();
    ~MyStack();
    ...
    ...
private:
    struct node;
    node* head;
    int _top;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyStack<T>::node {
    node(node*, T, T);
    T position_x;
    T position_y;
    node* next;
};
```

But what if I change the struct node in the private field into a class like this:

```
#ifndef MYSTACK_H_INCLUDED
#define MYSTACK_H_INCLUDED
#include <cstddef> // for std:size_t
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyStack{
public:
    MyStack();
    ~MyStack();
    ...
    ...
private:
    class Node {
        friend class MyStack<T>;
    public:
        Node(T, Node*);
    private:
        const T value; 
        Node *next;   
    };
    Node *head;  


};
#endif // MYSTACK_H_INCLUDED
```

Is it necessary to create another Class in Stack class for Node or I just use Struct ?
And Why ?

Comment: In C++, the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is the default "visibility" of members. For `struct` the default is for members to be `public`, for a `class` for members to be `private`.

Comment: Also, in the first case the structure _is_ a private structure in the `MyStack` class, just like the `Node` class is a private class in the second example. It's because it is declared inside the `MyStack`, and even if it's a forward declaration the scope is still to be inside the surrounding class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do what you are doing now whenever I desire not to expose internal data.  I define my linkedlist

```
template <class T>
class List{

    class Node{
    public:

         friend class List;              

    private:

         private members
    };

    public:
};
```

I prefer this style because I program in Java which makes use of inner and static inner classes in this very format which is comfortable for me.

You will need to encapsulate the private fields of Node to access them from List but other than that, you can define your classes as such and even using structs but recall only difference between class and struct is that struct members are public by default.